# How to deploy Strapi to Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, web-deployment, strapi

I installed Strapi with Mongodb locally. 
I need to deploy it to Azure.
Strapi is commitet on Azure Git-repository.
I have created a App Service with Ubuntu on Azure.

How to deploy my Strapi to this? 
Can I use pipeline? 
I can't find any good documentaion/example how to do it. Help!

```
*************
   UPDATE
*************
```

My results after trying the method described here:

https://github.com/youkou2/Strapi-On-Azure-WebApp

1. Build pipeline works without any error
2. Deploy pipeline works without any error
3. Deployed web site is empty.

I can describe what I have done, may be somebody can help me to find what I did wrong.

a) Build pipeline is

```
pool:
  name: Azure Pipelines
steps:
- bash: |
   yarn install 
   set NODE_ENV=PRODUCTION     
   yarn build  

   rm -rf .cache
   rm -rf .git
   displayName: Build

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: 'Archive ./'
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: ./
    includeRootFolder: false

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'

*** It works ok, no errors ***
```

b) Deploy pipeline

```
steps:
- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  displayName: 'Deploy Azure App Service'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '$(Parameters.ConnectedServiceName)'
    appType: '$(Parameters.WebAppKind)'
    WebAppName: '$(Parameters.WebAppName)'

*** It works ok, no errors ***
```

c) Project is deployed to https://oskogencms.azurewebsites.net/

[image]

```
*** It is empty, why? ***
enter code here
```

Here is additional info around the deployment:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try to use zip deploy to deploy your strapi, Maybe this article can help you: https://github.com/youkou2/Strapi-On-Azure-WebApp

Comment: Hi Bownman Zhy. I tried to deploy using article you shared. Could you please take a look at update of this case? :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use zip deploy, The steps is npm install, create zip package, publish zip package, release zip package. For more information please have a look of this the offcial doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-zip

By the way, it seems deploy strapi to azure web app is not the recommended method.

https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/deployment/azure.html#azure

This is an article on deploying strapi to azure web app, the introduction is more detailed, also using zip deployment:(The only different between you is it is deployed to windows os. If you can use ftp, ftp deploy is also a choice.)

https://github.com/youkou2/Strapi-On-Azure-WebApp

Answer (score 1):

Please check @ZiedBeta's sample in the following link:

https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/3580

```
Build pipeline:

    pool:
      name: Azure Pipelines
    steps:
    - bash: |

       yarn install 

       yarn build

       rm -rf .cache
       rm -rf .git
      displayName: build

    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive Strapi'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: ./
        includeRootFolder: false

    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'


Development pipeline:

    steps:
    - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
      displayName: 'Deploy Azure App Service'
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: '$(Parameters.ConnectedServiceName)'
        appType: '$(Parameters.WebAppKind)'
        WebAppName: '$(Parameters.WebAppName)'
        enableCustomDeployment: true
        DeploymentType: zipDeploy
```

Comment: Hi Cece Dong, Thank you for your post. It helped a lot to go forward, but I am still not in production. BUILD pipeline is OK. DEVELOPMENT pipeline build OK, but result is a page ":( Application Error. If you are the application administrator, you can access the diagnostic resources." I can see that Strapi is located /home/site/wwwroot with /build folder. What can be wrong? I run it on OS version: Unix 4.4.0.128.

Comment: Could you share detailed log in your original post? Did you try to add yourself to be a application administrator?

Comment: Hi Cece Dong, I have just updated my case with additional info. Could you please take a look at it? Contact me if you need more details. Thank you! :-)

Comment: Do you mean the application is deployed successfully with DevOps, but the application is not be able to lunched?

Comment: Yes, it does not. It dpeloyed on https://oskogencms.azurewebsites.net/ Open it and check the console. It returnes 500 on the first request. What kind problem is it? Thanks!

Comment: When you deploy Strapi to Azure locally from command line, will you get this issue?

Comment: You could also try  KUDU console by targetting https://sitename.scm.azurewebsites.net . You will be able to navigate in the debugging console to see the RAW logs from IIS.